# How to make animation of coordinate Y in opengl

Tags: python, opengl, 3d

I have a cylinder and I want to make animation of coordinate Y by law Y = Y*cos(t+Y). How can I make it only with OpenGL? What functions should I use? Maybe some examples?

```
def init():
    global xrot         
    global yrot         
    global ambient     
    global cylcolor    
    global lightpos     

    xrot = 0.0                         
    yrot = 0.0                      
    ambient = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1)       
    cylcolor = (0, 0, 1, 0.8)  
    lightpos = (2.0, 2.0, 0)        

    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)               
    gluOrtho2D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0)         
    glRotatef(-90, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)                  
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambient) 
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)                           
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)                           
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightpos)   

def draw():
    global xrot
    global yrot
    global lightpos
    global greencolor
    global cylcolor
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)                               
    glPushMatrix()                                            
    glRotatef(xrot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)                              
    glRotatef(yrot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)                          
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightpos)                
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, cylcolor)
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -0.7)                               
    glutSolidCylinder(0.5, 1, 20, 20)
    glPopMatrix()                                             
    glutSwapBuffers()
```

and then main part of program

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB)
glutInitWindowSize(300, 300)
glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50)
glutInit(sys.argv)
glutDisplayFunc(draw)
init()
glutMainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that drawing by `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences and the fixed function pipeline matrix stack is deprecated since decades.
Read about [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and see [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering.

---

Anyway, you have to call [`glutPostRedisplay`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node20.html), for continuously redisplaying the window.
Use [`glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node70.html) to get the number of milliseconds since `glutInit` was called.
A translation can be be performed by [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml).

Further I recommend to setup a depth buffer (focus on `GLUT_DEPTH`):

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH)
```

and to enable the [depth test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test). Don't forget to clear the depth buffer too:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) 
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
```

Add the following lines to your code, to perform a up and down movement along the y axis of the viewport:

```
import math
```

</>

```
def draw():
    global xrot, yrot, lightpos, greencolor, cylcolor
    
    timeSinceStart = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)
    
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)                               
    
    glPushMatrix()                              
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, math.cos(timeSinceStart*0.002))                 
    glRotatef(xrot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)                              
    glRotatef(yrot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)                          

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightpos)                
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, cylcolor)                            
    glutSolidCylinder(0.5, 1, 20, 20)
    glPopMatrix()                                             
    
    glutSwapBuffers()
    glutPostRedisplay()
```

I created the following animation with the changes applied to your original code, and I changed the following parameters:

```
xrot = 10.0  
lightpos = (2.0, -2.0, 1.0)
```

[image]

See also [Immediate mode and legacy OpenGL](https://github.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/blob/master/readme/content_python_legacy.md)

Comment: Thank you for your explaining but I have 2 questions. 
You wrote:"Add the following lines to your code, to perform a up and down movement along the y axis of the viewport:"
1) And why COS in glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, math.cos(timeSinceStart*0.002))  on 3 position?(This is Z axis)
2) Why  glTranslatef(0.0, math.cos(timeSinceStart*0.002), 0.0) do something strange animation?

Comment: @ИльшатМурзурбеков 1. because of `glRotatef(-90, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0) ` in the `init` function of your code which does a 90° rotation around the X axis (Z = Y and Y = -Z). 2. `timeSinceStart` is different in every frame so `math.cos(timeSinceStart*0.002)` is different in every frame and this causes the animation.

Comment: Got it! Am I true that glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, math.cos(timeSinceStart*0.002)) is for law Y=cos(t)? How can I make Y=cos(t+Y) for example?

Comment: @ИльшатМурзурбеков Yes it is *Y=cos(t)*. If you want *Y=cos(t+Y)* then you have to declare a global variable `float Y = 0.0f` and something like `Y=math.cos(timeSinceStart*0.001 + Y;` `glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, Y);`